# why does my pyplot show no lines?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, lines, points

I am new to pyplot and wondering what I'm doing wrong here.

I would like to plot a series of random line segments:

Here's some example code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def testPlot():
  minx = miny = -1
  maxx = maxy = 30
  # some points randomly generated
  points = [((10, 21), (19, 22)), ((11, 9), (22, 27)), ((9, 13), (5, 9)), ((18, 4), (2, 21)), ((25, 27
  for pair in points:
    print pair
    for point in pair:  #plot each point with a small dot
      x = point[0]
      y = point[1]
      plt.plot(x,y,'bo')
    # draw a line between the pairs of points
    plt.plot(pair[0][0],pair[0][1],pair[1][0],pair[1][1],color='r',linewidth=2)
  plt.axis([minx,maxx,miny,maxy])
  plt.show()
```

Here is what I get after running that, there should be lines between the points but where are the lines?

```
((10, 21), (19, 22))
((11, 9), (22, 27))
((9, 13), (5, 9))
((18, 4), (2, 21))
((25, 27), (11, 13))
```

[image: plotted points but no lines]

Thank you for any clues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the line of problem:

```
...
plt.plot(pair[0][0],pair[0][1],pair[1][0],pair[1][1],color='r',linewidth=2)
...
```

You're trying to draw the referring to `x,y,x1,y1`, which in fact should be `((x, x1), (y, y1))`. Correcting this seems working fine:

```
def testPlot():
  minx = miny = -1
  maxx = maxy = 30
  # some points randomly generated
  points = [((10, 21), (19, 22)), ((11, 9), (22, 27)), ((9, 13), (5, 9)), ((18, 4), (2, 21)), ((25, 27), (11, 13))]
  for pair in points:
    print pair
    for point in pair:  #plot each point with a small dot
      x = point[0]
      y = point[1]
      plt.plot(x,y,'bo')
    # change this line to ((x, x1), (y, y1)) 
    plt.plot((pair[0][0],pair[1][0]),(pair[0][1],pair[1][1]), color='r',linewidth=2)
  plt.axis([minx,maxx,miny,maxy])
  plt.show()
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: @slashdottir, not a problem, glad it helps :)